# Explain the output of following code?

Tags: c, recursion

```
void count(int n){
    static int d=1;
    printf("%d",n);
    printf("%d",d);
    d++;
    if(n>1) count(n-1);
    printf("%d",d);
}
int main(){
    count(3);
}
```

I'm new to programming,so please help me understand,why the output contains two more 4's even after the 'if' statement is false and the function is not recursively invoked after that?

Comment: Add the output to the question, please.

Comment: Now is a perfect time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through your code line by line while watching the variables and their values. If you do that the result you get should hopefully become obvious.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You forgot the obligatory link to Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ;)

Comment: `void main` has never been valid in either C or C++. Please don't post code with `void main` (FTFY). Also please restrict yourself to ***one language at a time***.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Although mentioning debugger is fair game in programs of small size, recursive debugging presents its unique challenges, which make it hard even for people with considerable experience in non-recursive debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a recursive call, you do not transfer control over to the function being called forever. If there is some unfinished work in the function making the call, it would get control back to finish the unfinished work once the recursive invocation is over.

In your case, the "unfinished business" is the last `printf` call. There are three invocations of `count`. Once the third invocation exits, the second one prints `d`, which is `4`, and exits. This, in turn, gives control back to the first invocation, which prints `4` again.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of `printf("%d",d);` at the end of the function.

And this statement is executed n number of times.

Unfolding the recursive calls of count(3), we get.

```
3
1
count(2)
d
```

on further unfolding, we get.

```
3
1
   2
   2
   count(1)
   d
d
```

Again on unfolding we get,

```
3
1
   2
   2
       1
       3
           ... recursion ends here
       d
   d
d
```

Comment: Last printf is called n times not n+1 times.

Comment: @2501, thanks. corrected, but the last n+1 values of printed``d`` will be same.

Comment: @ee2 the output is 312213444